# For finite sets $A$ and $B$, if $A+A=B+B$, does $A=B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the Minkowski sum of two finite sets defined by $A+A := \{x+y|x,y  \ \ \text{are elements of }A\}$, does $A+A=B+B$ imply $A=B$?

I have tried proof by contradiction, but I seem to be a bit stuck.

Comment: What is $+$? Are $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the elements of $A$ and $B$ are integer (or real) numbers -- no, that's not true. Consider $A=\{-2,-1,1,2\}$ and $B=A\cup\{0\}$.

To find this counterexample, I thought of a set with many repeating sums of elements, which is an arithmetic progression, and removed an element that had to contribute to many of the repeated sums.